# Photoshop "Save as PDF" doesn't retain the transparency

Tags: adobe-photoshop, pdf, transparency

So I have this PSD with several transparent layers.
As I need to hand out the file for a professional printing, I export it through Photoshop (CS5) using the usual PDF/X-4:2008 PDF 1.4 profile to retain the transparency.

But the written PDF doesn't have any transparency :

- when I open it under Adobe Reader (with the transparency rendering option set to on), it has a white background
- when I open it under Photoshop, it also has that white background which means the transparency is not kept

So I guess there's something wrong with the layers as the profile used is the correct one, but I don't know what.
Any hint ?

Comment: The PDFx format does not support transparency. Why do you need transparency if this is for press?

Comment: Logo printing on white clothes. Also, yes, the X/4 standard allows transparency : http://www.iso.org/iso/iso_catalogue/catalogue_tc/catalogue_detail.htm?csnumber=42876

Comment: Well, I get no transparency ever if a Photoshop file is saved as PDFx. This may be a shortcoming of Photoshop. Illustrator seems to save the transparency with no issue.

Comment: Do you export (as you say in the text) or "save as" (as in the header)? Have you tried both?

Comment: I used "Save as", you can't make a PDF with the "Export" option :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After specifying the name of your file, you should get a Save Adobe PDF window with a set of options.
At the top, under Adobe PDF Preset: choose [High Quality Print]. This will preserve your transparency settings.

Comment: You can see what each preset does (including whether it flattens transparency or not) here: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/photoshop/cs/using/WS23B45D06-1977-4006-8BEB-2DBB08CA502Ea.html

Comment: I'll try that next time thanks :)
Though it also says "This preset creating ISO PDF/X-4:2008 files supports live transparency (transparency is not flattened)", so I'm still clueless on why this doesn't work here.

Comment: This answer doesn't seem to be holding up these days. I tried converting a file to High Quality Print settings and still did not get the transparency I needed in the final file.

Comment: @user147048, how can you tell it didn't work?

Comment: Photoshop has changed a bit since 2012. For Photoshop CC, make sure you check "Preserve Photoshop Editing Capabilities" in the PDF specific options. I tested this with both High Quality Print and Press Quality and they both worked for me.

As for how to tell if it worked or not, re-open the saved PDF file in Photoshop. If transparency didn't save, the background will be white instead of the classic transparency checkerboard.